Why Agamemnon? (Gabriela Mistral: Ronda de los colores)
Gabriela Mistral's poem Ronda de los colores contains the following stanza:

El amarillo se viene
grande y lleno de fervor
y le abren paso todos
como viendo a Agamenón.

Literally translated, this means the following:

Yellow is coming
big and full of fervour
and everyone makes way for it
as if seeing Agamemnon.

Ursula K. Le Guin even says "great Agamemnon" in her translation. Why precisely Agamemnon? Based on the Iliad, the Odyssey, the Epic Cycle and the plays in which he is a character, he is not the most glorious hero or king in Greek antiquity. As Wikipedia points out,

Agamemnon's family history had been tarnished by murder, incest, and treachery, consequences of the heinous crime perpetrated by his ancestor, Tantalus, and then of a curse placed upon Pelops, son of Tantalus, by Myrtilus, whom he had murdered.

While preparing to set sail for Troy, he offends the goddess Artemis, so he is forced to sacrifice his daughter Iphigenia. On his return from the Trojan War he is killed by his wife Clytemnestra (exacting vengeance for the death of Iphigenia) or by Aegisthus (in other versions of the story). One book calls him a pathetic despot.
It seems to me that mythological heroes such as Theseus and Perseus deserve more admiration than Agamemnon. Since the poem does not rhyme, rhyme was not the reason why Agamemnon (or Spanish "Agamenón") was preferred over the name of a different hero.
According to the article The Symbolism of Colors in Ancient Greek Mythology,

Yellow is a color that is often associated with wealth and power in Greek mythology. The god Apollo, the god of the sun, was often depicted in shades of yellow, symbolizing his radiance and strength. Yellow was also associated with knowledge and wisdom, as seen in the god Hermes, the messenger of the gods, who was often depicted in yellow attire.

I could not find a connection between yellow and Agamemnon in the Iliad. However, Agamemnon is associated with wealth, in the book chapter The Characterization of Agamemnon in the Iliad in Agamemnon, the Pathetic Despot, where Andrew Porter writes,

Agamemnon’s shamelessness is also given characteristics in Iliad 1. It seeks personal gain (κερδαλεόφρον, 149) and wealth (πλοῦτον, 171). Achilles’ earlier speech had characterized Agamemnon through his address as “[the] greatest lover of things of all men” (φιλοκτεανώτατε πάντων, 1.122).

But the same paragraph also points out that,

Agamemnon is demonstrating a complete dearth of leadership qualities expected of the paramount basileus. He is acting most thoughtlessly in his selfishness.

Even though the Greek warriors before Troy made way for him, Le Guin's "great Agamemnon" sounds almost ironic, and it is not clear to me whether Mistral could have had this in mind. So I repeat my question: why Agamemnon?

Four of the verses end in the same sound as Agamenón: verde-limón, campeón and ladrón.

In the Iliad, Agamemnon was in charge of the Greek forces.  The point is not that he is admirable or any other virtue.  It's that he is in command.  Consequently, everyone would get out of his way.
"Great" can just be a reference to his power, not to anything more complimentary.

"The point is not that he is admirable or any other virtue." How can you know that without even looking at the poem?

@Mary  I remember a story where Agamemnon was described as having obtained a direct commission in the army because of his connection to the royal family.   And that  joke is a about as accurate as you saying he was "in charge of the Greek forces", like he was appointed by the monarch to be the general.  Agamemnon was described as the overlord of all the kings in Greece.  The Greek kings besieging Troy were his political subordinates obeying his orders.  Like a medieval king leading his vassal dukes, counts, and lords to invade a foreign country, he led his vassal kings to invade Troy.

@Mary I remember a joke about the Iliad where Agamemnon was described as getting a direct commission in the army because of his relation to the royal family, and that joke is about as accurate as you writing he was in charge of the Greek forces, like he was a general commanding the invasion.  According the myths, Agamemnon was the overlord of all Greek kings, and he led his vassal kings to invade Troy the way a medieval European king would have led his vassal dukes, counts, and lords to invade another kingdom.

Yes, but initially upon his return they would have also been in awe, wouldn't they? ||thecollector.com/agamemnon-armies-catalogue-of-ships The Armies of Agamemnon King of Kings Legendary leader Agamemnon was the high King of one of the largest armies in ancient Greece.

@Tsundoku  You provided the poem.  How can you say I didn't look at it?

Which of the four sentences in your answer shows evidence that you have read the poem?

You made the accusation, you need to provide evidence that I didn't.

In Greek myth, Agamemnon was the Anax, the overlord of all the Greek kings.  So he was a great king, or a high king, or a king of kings.
The Greek word anax comes from the earlier word wanax, and according to writings in the linear B script from Mycenean Greek there were men with the position of wanax.  There is a possibility that Agamemnon was a real life  wanax. During the Greek Dark Ages writing stopped, and when writing resumed centuries later in the Greek Alphabet the usual title for a king was basileus.
And the historical Greek kings with the title of basileus ruled tiny little Greek city states, except for kings of larger kingdoms like Macedonia in the north.
So to the classical Greeks the anax, the overlord of many kings who had the title of basileus, was an awesomely powerful person.
Agamemnon had a position in legend - and possibly in real life, if he was a real person - which was never equaled in historic times until King Philip II of Macedon and his son King Alexander III forced all the Greek city states to join their military league.  And of course the difference is that according to the myths, Agamemnon was the recognized lawful overlord of all Greece, while Philip II and Alexander III had to invade Greece and defeat many Greek city states in battles to gain their position, which rested entirely upon their military might.
If Gabriella Mistral compared the position of Agamemnon to the situation in historical ancient Greece, she would have considered him to have had a great and powerful political position, if not necessarily to have been a great and noble man.  And she would have believed all of the Greeks at the time of the Trojan War would have been in awe of the greatness of his position as anax and would have made way for him.
According to the Bible, Solomon ruled a kingdom in the Middle East much larger than archaeologists think probable.  According to some Muslim stories, King Solomon, or Sulayman ibn Dawud, ruled the whole world, and was the ruler of all animals, and the ruler of supernatural beings like the Jinn. Those stories describe him as the greatest ruler of all time. And if Gabriella Mistral knew of those Muslim stories, she might have considered naming Solomon instead of Agamemnon.
According to the Shahnameh of Ferdowsi (written c. 977-1010) the mythical king Fereydun divided his realm among his three sons Salm, Tur, and Iraj.  Salm got Rum, more or less modern Turkey or the entire Roman Empire, Tur got Turan, more or less Central Asia, and Iraj got Iran. So obviously  Fereydun was believed to have ruled a very large part of the world as known to Ferdowsi.
According to the Shahnameh, the first king, and founder of the Pishdadian Dynasty, was Keyumars, who was so powerful that all men, all domestic animals, and all wild animals obeyed him. Keyumars's grandson Hushang was the second King of the World. Tamuras, son of Hushang, was the 3rd King of the World.  Jamshid, son of Tamuras, was the fourth King of the World, and reigned for 700 years before being overthrown by the tyrant Zahhak. Fereydun who overthrew Zahhak was said to be the last monarch of the world.
So If Gabriella Mistral was familiar with the Shahnameh, she might have decided to mention one of the Pishdadian kings instead of Agamemnon.

Fróði's Peace (Old Norse: Fróðafrið) is a semi-legendary period of peace throughout Northern Europe that is referenced in Nordic mythology, skaldic poetry and historical accounts.

Early Scandinavians may have believed that long ago a Scandinavian monarch Frodi ruled the world and enforced peace throughout the world, creating a brief golden age, the Peace of Frode or Frodi.  Of course as Scandinavian geographical and historical knowledge increased Scandinavian scholars would have realized how improbable a Scandinavian king ruling the whole world would have been.
The new testament sometimes gives the impression that the Roman Empire ruled the whole world.  I have read somewhere that some medieval Europeans believed that Augustus, the first Roman Emperor, ruled the whole world and brought peace to the entire world.  So his reign would be the perfect time for Jesus Christ to be born.  Similarly, if the second Emperor, Tiberius, was the ruler of the whole world and of all men, Pontius Pilate would be acting on the authority of the government of all men, and the sacrifice of Christ would thus be an offering by all men and bring the possibility of salvation to all men.
So Snorri Sturluson (1179-1241) combined both ideas.

Snorri Sturluson's prose prologue to Grottasöngr describes that at the time of the birth of Jesus and the Pax Romana, the most powerful king at the time in Northern Europe was the Skjöldung Fróði and the peace was attributed to him.[4]


In contrast to this, Snorri then describes how Frodi in fact was using the jötnar, Fenja and Menja, who he bought from the Yngling, King Fjölnir of Sweden to grind peace, gold and happiness from an enchanted millstone. Following this, feuding ceased. Theft would also not occur and a ring left on Jelling heath would lie for a long time.[4]
After being overworked, Fenja and Menja use the mill to summon an army to free them and kill the king, ending Fróði's Peace.[4]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%B3%C3%B0i%27s_Peace#Prose_Edda
So if Gabriella Mistral knew of the legends that Frodi once ruled and brought peace to the whole world, she might have mentioned him instead of Agamemnon.  And if she knew of legends That Augustus and Tiberius ruled and brought peace to the whole world, she might have mentioned them instead of Agamemnon.

I don't get the point of second guessing a poet. I think her image is: the people hailed him upon his return.

Gabriela Mistral was very familiar with classical works of Greek literature. Apart from the Bible, she said that she found most inspiration from Shakespeare, Calderón [often called "the Shakespeare of Spain"], Rubén Darío, and especially Homer. Indeed Minerva Alganza Roldán wrote1 that:

sin duda, los clásicos de la Antigüedad más influyentes en Gabriela
Mistral fueron los que llamó «padres trágicos griegos». Concretamente,
los protagonistas de la Orestiada y del ciclo sofocleo sobre Edipo
habitan en sus versos, desde los primeros  poemarios  hasta  los
inéditos a su muerte,

which I would translate as:

without a doubt, the most influential classics of Antiquity on
Gabriela Mistral were those she called the “Greek tragic fathers”.
Specifically, the protagonists of the Oresteia and the Sophoclean
cycle on Oedipus inhabit her verses, from the first collections of
poems to those unpublished at the time of her death

Among the poems she wrote based on Greek tragedies were "Electra en la niebla" ("Electra in the mist"), "Clitemnestra" and "Casandra". These final two both contained references to Agamemnon, so it is interesting to look at them to see what image Mistral had in mind of him.
In "Clitemnestra" Mistral writes:

y de esta brasa todos arderemos, 
Agamenón hasta el último día: 
tu palacio, tus mirtos, tus palomas, 
con un rey de hombres y una reina loca

describing Agamemnon as "a king of men", while in "Casandra" she writes something very similar:

Antes del alba habré recuperado 
yo al Agamenón, al rey de hombres 
en él voy de vuelo, ya voy de vuelo.

"Agamemnon, the king of men". In both cases she refers to him using the Homerian epithet "lord of men" (ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν, ánax andrôn). It seems reasonable that Mistral had the same image in mind when she wrote the line about yellow in "Ronda de los colores": that everybody makes way for its progress in the way that people stand back to let the high king through.
Rodolfo Oroz in Estudios mistralianos writes that for Mistral the color yellow usually symbolised "aging, decay, of that which is close to death". This, however, does not seem to fit the triumphal, joyous air of the poem.

"Los clásicos de Gabriela Mistral", Myrtia 27, 415-425 (2012).


I think that reading is a bit of stretch. Those examples in that book are clearly of decay and death, yes.  But here yellow is triumphant and it compares yellow to Agamennon's (home)coming and everyone making way for him. But he is not heading toward anything but home.

It's a fair point.
